# Sparse data: efficient storage and retrieval in an RDBMS

Tags: sql, mysql, hibernate, postgresql, sparse-matrix

I have a table representing values of source file metrics across project revisions, like the following:

```
Revision FileA FileB FileC FileD FileE ...
1           45     3    12   123   124
2           45     3    12   123   124
3           45     3    12   123   124
4           48     3    12   123   124
5           48     3    12   123   124
6           48     3    12   123   124
7           48    15    12   123   124
```

(The relational view of the above data is different.  Each row contains the following columns: Revision, FileId, Value.  The files and their revisions from which the data is calculated are stored in Subversion repositories, so we're trying to represent the repository's structure in a relational schema.)

There can be up to 23750 files in 10000 revisions (this is the case for the [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) drawing program).  As you can see, most values are the same between successive revisions, so the table's useful data is quite sparse.  I am looking for a way to store the data that

- avoids replication and uses space efficiently (currently the non-sparse representation requires 260 GB (data+index) for less than 10% of the data I want to store)
- allows me to retrieve efficiently the values for a specific revision using an SQL query (without explicitly looping through revisions or files)
- allows me to retrieve efficiently the revision for a specific metric value.

Ideally, the solution should not depend on a particular [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) and should be compatible with [Hibernate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate_%28Java%29).  If this is not possible, I can live with using Hibernate, MySQL or PostgreSQL-specific features.

Comment: I'm not sure that I entirely understand what you're tracking. Revision 4 has two separate values for FileB? If you want revision 4, how do you know which value to use?

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo, I forgot to change the Revision after copy-pasting the row.  I corrected now the data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how I might model it. I've left out the Revisions table and Files table as those should be pretty self-explanatory.

```
CREATE TABLE Revision_Files
(
    start_revision_number   INT NOT NULL,
    end_revision_number     INT NOT NULL,
    file_number             INT NOT NULL,
    value                   INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Revision_Files PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (start_revision_number, file_number),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_Revision_Files_start_before_end CHECK (start_revision_number <= end_revision_number)
)
GO
```

To get all of the values for files of a particular revision you could use the following query. Joining to the files table with an outer join would let you get those that have no defined value for that revision.

```
SELECT
    REV.revision_number,
    RF.file_number,
    RF.value
FROM
    Revisions REV
INNER JOIN Revision_Files RF ON
    RF.start_revision_number <= REV.revision_number AND
    RF.end_revision_number >= REV.revision_number
GO
```

Assuming that I understand correctly what you want in your third point, this will let you get all of the revisions for which a particular file has a certain value:

```
SELECT
    REV.revision_number
FROM
    Revision_Files RF
INNER JOIN Revisions REV ON
    REV.revision_number BETWEEN RF.start_revision_number AND RF.end_revision_number
WHERE
    RF.file_number = @file_number AND
    RF.value = @value
GO
```

Comment: Excellent - thanks!  It seems that ranges are the way to go.  I also admire your expert use of SQL for the table definition.